# React Navigation - createStackNavigator Error - "Undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I've created the following code to import into app.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from '../screens/auth/ProfileScreen';
import FilterScreen from '../screens/FilterScreen';

  const Routes = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Home: {
          screen: HomeScreen
        },
        Filters: {
          screen: FilterScreen
        },
        Profile: {
          screen: ProfileScreen
        }
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: "Home",
        navigationOptions: {
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "#fff",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff"
        }
      }
    );

    export default Routes;
```

I'm importing into app.js as follows

```
import Routes from './navigation/StackNavigator';
```

When I preview my app at this stage, I receive the following error:

```
undefined is not a function (near '...(0, 

_reactNavigation.createStackNavigator)...')

<unknown>
    C:\Apps\test\app\navigation\StackNavigator.js:9:6
loadModuleImplementation
    C:\Apps\test\app\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:213:12
<unknown>
    C:\Apps\test\app\App.js:7
loadModuleImplementation
    C:\Apps\test\app\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:213:12
<unknown>
    C:\Apps\test\app\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js:2
loadModuleImplementation
    C:\Apps\test\app\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:213:12
guardedLoadModule
    C:\Apps\test\app\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:140:45
global code
    <unknown file>:0
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong? I'm tearing my hair out! Any suggestion will be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: I feel like you would get a different error message, but are you 100% certain its installed properly?

Comment: I believe so! It was working perfectly before I tried to add this. I’m using the TabNavigator which works, so react navigator must be installed okay!?

Comment: what version of react-navigation are you using?

Comment: Version 2.17.0 - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- Rename Routes to something else e.g. `Routes1` (in both `app.js` and `navigation/StackNavigator`)
- Narrow the scope of the error e.g. remove options from `createStackNavigator` and try something like:

  `const Routes1 = createStackNavigator();`

  `export default Routes1;`
- Try the tab navigator in this file (instead of stackNavigator) and see if it works ok.
- Cleanup and do the forced reinstall of modules

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried renaming Routes to Routes1 but that didn’t work. I removed all options and that didn’t work either. tabNavigator spits out the same error :(

Comment: can you edit the question and add details about the error you get for when you try `tabNavigation`, also you can insert a few nop lines (e.g. comments) and see if the error you're getting is different (different line:column). If you end up getting the same then it might mean you need to figure out why are your changes not picked up...